# how to send data with Readable stream from NodeJS to C++

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I'm currently sending data from C++ to NodeJS passing a NodeJS `readableStream.push.bind(readableStream)` to the C++ binding code and writing onto the stream from C++ using

```
Napi::Function push = info[0].As<Napi::Function>();
Napi::ThreadSafeFunction push_safe = Napi::ThreadSafeFunction::New(env, push, "push", 0, 1);
push_safe.BlockingCall(data, custom_callback);
```

Now I want to be able to send data to the C++ binding, using a NodeJS Stream, but I can't figure out if C++ can accept a Stream, and calling a C++ version of `.on('data', (data) => {})` on it, something like:

example NodeJS:

```
const read_stream = fs.createReadStream("./random.bin");
mybinding.myfunc(read_stream);
```

example C++:

```
Value myfunc(const CallbackInfo& info) {
  Env env = info.Env();

  auto on_data_lambda = [](data)
  {
    std::cout << "new data arrived from nodejs stream: " << data << std::endl;
  }

  /*some magic*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing this with all the bells and whistles is not trivial. As always, the most complex part is handling all the errors.

I suggest you go check in Node.js sources `src/js_stream.cc` which contains something similar and you will understand why a good/fast implementation is difficult.

If you want to keep it simple, you can start by creating a JS reference to your C++ `on_data` function.

Then you can register this function as an event receiver.

```cpp
Napi::Value ondata(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info) {
  if (!info[0].IsObject()) printf("Something strange received");
  else printf("received %s\n", info[0].ToString().Utf8Value().c_str());
  return info.Env().Undefined();
}

Napi::Value stream(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info) {
  Napi::Object stream = info[0].ToObject();
  Napi::Function on_data_ref = Napi::Function::New(info.Env(), ondata, "on_data");
  Napi::Value onValue = stream.Get("on");
  if (!onValue.IsFunction()) throw Napi::Error::New(info.Env(), "This is not an event emitter");
  Napi::Function on = onValue.As<Napi::Function>();
  on.Call(stream, {Napi::String::New(info.Env(), "data"), on_data_ref});
  return info.Env().Undefined();
}
```

If you do this, data will start flowing. But you still have to do correctly the error handling and everything else.

Comment: It looks like it's not working. I'm thinking about implementing a custom streambuf using the stream data to fill the internal buffer and using it to feeding an istream..what do you think?

Comment: I compiled and tested my example - it works for me. You can use a `streambuf` but it will be wasteful because all the copying.